# Setting Alarm for Multiple times in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

In my app I want alarms for several times which will be set by the user.
But if I set the alarm for a different date and time it only responds on the last set-up time.

Such as if I set alarm for date `20-01-2017` time `10.10 am`,
`20-01-2017` time `10.20 am`, `20-01-2017` time `10.30 am`,
and so on it only gives the alarm for last selected date & Time.
But doesn't give alarm at `20-01-2017` time `10.10 am`, `20-01-2017` time `10.20 am`, or other selected times.

How can I get alarm at all selected times?
Here is my code:

```
public void setDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void setTime(View view) {

    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}


public void setAlarm(View view) {
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmMin);
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, alarmDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.YEAR, alarmYear);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MONTH, alarmMonth);

    setAlarmN(calSet);
}

private void setAlarmN(Calendar targetCal) {

makeText(this, "Alarm is set at" + targetCal.getTime(),
        LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
        pendingIntent);


}

//date picker fragment
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        alarmDay = day;
        alarmYear = year;
        alarmMonth = month;
    }
}

//Time picker fragment
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        alarmHour = hourOfDay;
        alarmMin = minute;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use different intent IDs to fire it multiple time. Using same ID means you cancel previous scheduling, and set new one.

Comment: I am not Clear about this.can u give me an example how can i use different  intent IDs to solve the problem?

Comment: `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` has 4 parameters 2nd parameter is request ID. You use `RQS_1`. Try using different IDs for every alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `void setAlarmN()` method. You can't generate alarm notification with the same id. That should mean that notification before gets cancel and override. Try to set unique id for `RQS_1` each time `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` gets called. Probably you have to declare private variable and increment it.

Comment: i have used       {private int RQS_1;                                                       RQS_1 = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();} But still same problem.